# What is the difference between !( i%2) vs (i%2 == 0)?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
if (i%2 == 0)
console.log( i + "is even number")
else
console.log(i + "is not even")
```

}

working, but

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
if (!i%2)
console.log( i + "is even number")
else
console.log(i + "is not even")
```

}

not working , why ? 
and when would i%2 becomes true ?

Comment: !(i%2) - brackets are important

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
if (!(i%2))
console.log( i + "is even number")
else
console.log(i + "is not even")
}
```

You need to look at [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

**What went wrong?**

As per operator precedence `!i%2` is evaluated as `(!i)%2` Hence, for every value of `i` greater than 0, `!i` becomes `false` and `false%2` is 0

Comment: p.s. not sure why a correct answer would be downvoted

Comment: @nikhil So what happens if i put ! i ? I mean how it is interpreted ?

Comment: I guess OP is asking the _difference_, perhaps it does not provide so!

Comment: @RayonDabre - OP knows about i%2 == 0,however, is confused why the other is not working. Hence, targeted OP's confusion

Answer (score 2):

Because the *logical NOT* (`!`) operator takes precedence over the *remainder* operator (`%`). So your code is actually evaluated as:

```
((!i)%2)
```

Which will always return `false` (except when `i` is `0`).

Try this instead:

```
if (!(i%2))
```

See [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: if i = 0, that mean `!false % 2` => 1(true). And if i = 1, that mean `!true % 2` => 0 (false)

Answer (score 1):

define a variable as i % 2 first, then it could work as a boolean.

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
var a = i%2;
if (!a)
console.log( i + "is even number")
else
console.log(i + "is not even")
}
```

or enclose in parenthesis. It didn't work because it is being interpreted as "not i" first before doing % 2, it should be calculated first i.e. "not (i % 2)"